# How to pull the past two years of data, but not the data in the current month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull the data from the past two years, starting from the the past month (not taking into account the current month).
So it will pull all 2 years of data starting from 09/30/2021.
I've tried the following, but the months after September for 2020 get taken out:

```
WHERE YEAR(ACCDAT_0) >= (YEAR(GETDATE()) -2) AND MONTH(ACCDAT_0) < MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))
```

Comment: You want 09/30/2019 to 09/30/2021?

Comment: The problem is you're checking the month and year and year separately. The year must be 2019 or more AND the month must be less than October. That filters out October 2019 and October 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following logic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ACCDAT_0 >= DATEADD(year, -2, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND
      ACCDAT_0 < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE();
SET @d = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), MONTH(@d), 1);

SELECT ... WHERE ACCDAT_0 >= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @d)
             AND ACCDAT_0 <  @d;
```

- Several helpful date articles here, including why you want range queries and not things like `YEAR(column)`: [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Comment: What would you say to `dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I used that trick for a long time, but I find it bulkier and unintuitive in that it includes the "magic" date of 0. I explain why I like `DATEFROMPARTS` so much more [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/).